# Absolute positioned DIV element spreads over and blocks buttons, how to hide the invisible block?

Tags: css, html

I have an absolute positioned logo on the bottom left of my website... BUT the problem is that ive positioned it to stick to the right of the page but it leaves a invisible barrier to the left of it that spreads across the page. So lets say a link is placed in alignment with that footer element, I won't be able to click it, the absolute positioned layer is spreading over it (even though nothings in it)

Heres my CSS for the logos position:

```
#basemenu {
margin-right: auto;
position: fixed;
bottom:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
text-align:right;
right:1%;
}
```

Comment: `I have an absolute positioned logo on the bottom left`.. `ive positioned it to stick to the right of the page` - where is it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an `img` inside of a `<div id='basemenu'></div>`. Is that right?

We could really use a block of HTML if you wouldn't mind posting it.

What I don't understand is why you can't target the logo itself with a bit of CSS like this:

```
#basemenu img {
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following block property `display : none;` to hide the block